# table disappears when more layers are added to a leaflet map

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, reactable

I created an interactive map along with `reactable` which I use to show points on the map and the other way round (user can select area on the map using button on the left to filter corresponding data in a table). The issue is that when I want to add more than 1 layer (another `addCircleMarkers`) then the whole table disappears when I select any row. So, it all works fine with one layer, doesn't work with more than 1. Is it possible to add additional layers in this case?

Here is reproducible code (please uncomment 2-nd `addCircleMarkers` layer to see disappearing table):

```
library(crosstalk)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(reactable)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tagList(
      leaflet::leafletOutput("map"),
      reactable::reactableOutput("table")             
              ))
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # data to render in a table
  data_all <- quakes %>%
    dplyr::select(depth, mag, stations) %>%
    crosstalk::SharedData$new(group = "volcano")
  
  
  # data to render on a map
  df_sf <- quakes %>%
    sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326)
  
  df_sf_ALL <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(df_sf, group = "volcano")
  
  df_less_20 <- quakes %>%
    dplyr::filter(stations<20) %>% 
    sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326) 
  
  df_more_20 <- quakes %>%
    dplyr::filter(stations>20) %>% 
    sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326) 
  
  df_sf_less_20 <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(df_less_20, group = "volcano")
  df_sf_more_20 <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(df_more_20, group = "volcano")
  


  output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
    leaflet::leaflet(df_sf_ALL) %>%
      leaflet::addTiles() %>%
      #leaflet::addCircleMarkers(data = df_sf_less_20, fillColor = "red", stroke = FALSE) %>% 
      leaflet::addCircleMarkers(data = df_sf_more_20, fillColor = "green", stroke = FALSE)
})

  output$table <- reactable::renderReactable({
    reactable::reactable(
    data_all,
    selection = "multiple",
    onClick = "select",
    rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer"),
    minRows = 10
  )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Very strange indeed. Hotfix: keep the full data and add a column `color` that is used inside a single leaflet `addCircleMarkers`. Does not tackle the weird behavior in any way though.

Comment: Ok, thanks. `crosstalk` seemed best way to do this but now I guess I need to find another way to make it work.

Comment: I would encourage you to also file an issue on their github project. Although it does not solely touch `crosstalk`, there seems to be a severe mixup with leaflet. I have no clue what is going on there but maybe they have. Good luck :)

Comment: Sure, thanks, I will;)